# how can I read values from groovy g:select in my controller

Tags: grails, groovy

I have several g:selects in my gsp that I want to use for filtering a query. How can I access their values in the controller? Here is a select that I have:

```
<td><g:select name="accts" from="${accountSelection}"/></td>
```

Here is how I populate the list

```
def filter() {
    def allaccts = getAccountSelection()
    [accountInstanceList:allaccts.accountInstanceList]
}
def getAccountSelection() {
    params.max = 10
    def accts = []
    accts.add("all")
    Account.list().each { item -> accts.add(item) }
    [accountInstanceList: accts, accountInstanceTotal: Account.count()]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller it's just another parameter.  You can access it like this:

```
params?.accts?.each { 
  println it
}
```